# Using temporary object by non-const reference within a single statement in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, lifetime, temporary

Here is the code:

```
namespace NS
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        template<typename T> friend B& operator<<(B& b, T const& obj);
    };

    template<typename T> B& operator<<(B& b, T const& obj)
    {
        // using b and obj
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    NS::B() << 2.71 << 123 << "abcdef"; // doesn't compile in gcc
    NS::B b; b << 2.71 << 123 << "abcdef"; // OK
}
```

The first line in main compiles in VS2015 (and some earlier ones) and doesn't compile in gcc (I tried in 6.3, 4.3.2).

Which compiler does the right thing?
I thought the temporary object's (NS::B()) lifetime would be up to the end of the statement (;), so it's ok to pass it to my operator<< by non-const reference.
If it isn't so, could you tell me why?

Thanks.

Comment: It's an MSVC extension.  Been in the compiler since about VC 6 and kept in because it would break too much existing code.  It can be turned off with a compiler switch.

Comment: `GCC` does the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

The standard says that temporary objects may not be converted to non-const lvalue references implicitly.  See [dcl.init.ref]/8.6.3.5.2 in n4628.

> Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be
>   const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference. [ Example:
>
> ```
> double& rd2 = 2.0; // error: not an lvalue and reference not const
> int i = 2;
> double& rd3 = i; // error: type mismatch and reference not const
> ```
>
> — end example ]

To solve this:

```
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&&t){return t;}
```

This function takes an rvalue `t` and returns an lvalue reference.

```
as_lvalue(NS::B()) << 2.71 << 123 << "abcdef";
```

The above is both standard compliant and safe.

Comment: Could you point out where the Standard says that temporary objects may not be converted to non-const references even inside the expression where this temporary object is guaranted (according to 12.2) to exist?

Comment: @some citation added

Comment: Unfortunately, in 8.6.3.5.2 and further all examples are about defining an explicit reference that potentially can have a longer lifetime than the object it points to. And there is no arguing about it - such references cannot be non-const. But in my example there is no explicit definition of a separate reference, the reference occurs only inside the expression with operator<< and there is no way it could live longer than that expression. So I'm not sure that paragraph covers my case. Well, maybe I missed something.

Comment: @some You are inventing a distinction that the standard does not make.  It gives valid cases, then it says "failing those valid cases, the reference must be an rvalue reference or const".  None of the earlier cases apply; there is no "it is a function argument reference being bound to an rvalue" clause.  So we evaluate that clause, which makes your code illegal.